# Multiple-sample z-test for proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Let's say I want to do a multiple-sample z-test for proportions. Is there any way to rank them?

How would I compare more than two samples at once?

Comment: What do you mean by 'rank them'?

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly used - and fairly basic - multisample extension of a two-sample proportions test (akin to the relationship between two-sample t-tests and ANOVA) is the test of homogeneity of proportions.

When you condition on both margins, this is the same as the chi-square test of independence - same test statistic and degrees of freedom.

Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution).

Any stats package worth the name will do one of these for you easily.

You don't have to rely on the chi-square approximation; it's possible to do an exact test (either akin to a Fisher test in the 2x2 table, or based on the chi-square statistic itself).

Many packages also make such exact tests straightforward. There's also approaches that don't require you to condition on both margins.

A search [here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=homogeneity+proportion) will turn up some useful discussion; a wider internet search has many useful resources.